# logistic regression formula gives inaccurate decision boundary

Tags: regression, logistic, classification

I have the following function:

```
def binary_classify(X1, X2, Y, classA):
    b0 = 0.0
    b1 = 0.0
    b2 = 0.0
    learning_rate = 0.3
    total_epochs = 100
    for _ in range(total_epochs):
        for x1, x2, y in zip(X1, X2, Y):
            if x1 != x1 or x2 != x2 or y != y:
                continue
            y = 1.0 if y == classA else 0.0

            prediction = None
            try:
                prediction = 1.0 / (1 + math.exp(-(b0 + b1 * x1 + b2 * x2)))
            except OverflowError:
                prediction = 0.0
            modifier = learning_rate * (y - prediction)
            b0 += modifier
            b1 += modifier * x1
            b2 += modifier * x2
    return (b0, b1, b2)
```

`X1`, `X2` are 2 columns of variables, `Y` is a column of different classes each variable falls into, `classA` is the class we are testing against (one vs all)

I have then plotted a graph displaying a scatter plot with each color being a different class. I also plotted a line for each color which represents the decision boundary. The desicion boundary is calculated via the formula: `y = (-b1 / b2)x - (b0 / b2)`
[image]

The problem is that the red decision boundary didn't even fit on this plot, and the blue one cuts the blue dot cluster in half... so something seems wrong.

***additional notes:***

The values `b0, b1, b2` actually seem to diverge when i increase the `total_epochs` value however the decision boundary line doesn't change.

---

replacing this line:

```
modifier = learning_rate * (y - prediction)
```

with:

```
modifier = learning_rate * (y - prediction) * prediction * (1 - prediction)
```

gives a different plot with converging values of `b0, b1, b2`, however the red decision boundary still looks wrong and is [apparently bad for multi classification](https://machinelearningmastery.com/logistic-regression-tutorial-for-machine-learning/#comment-426434)

[image]

Comment: My advice would be first decreasing your learning constant and try again; and plot your loss function across epochs to see if it oscillates or gets smaller.